# URL Rewrite on Public and Local Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using Codeigniter and trying to get my URL rewrites to work on both my public server and my local server.

When I'm on my public server, my `.htaccess` file in the root of my project needs to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sesamo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But then when on my public server it needs to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sesamorepair.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sesamorepair.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I make a simple `.htaccess` file that removes index.php from the url successfully from both local and public environments?

I did try putting them both together like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sesamorepair.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sesamorepair.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /sesamo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This worked on my local server but gave me an internal server error on my public server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the difference is the rewriting of `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` - you could probably avoid this issue by using `www.your.local` instead of `your.local` in your development environment and making your `.htaccess` file environment agnostic

Comment: Your local environment is presumably `http://mysite.dev` or something like that, production is `http://sesamorepair.com` but you want to redirect users to `http://www.sesamorepair.com` - you can't put that same redirect condition into your *local* htaccess because your local environment isn't set up for the `www.` part of the URL - my suggestion is to add it to your local Apache configuration so you can use the same rewrite rule for production and local